# smtp relay solution needed

Tags: smtp, open-source, relay

I am hosting my email server (postfix, dovecot) at home. I cannot send emails as my ISP does not allow connection via port 25. I have a linux server in the cloud with a public IP and I would like to use it as an SMTP relay (with authentication) for my email server.  Is there any open source SMTP relay? 
Thank you.
Regards
Zak

Comment: Name Operating System (or Linux distribution) you plan to use.

Comment: Debian/ubuntu or Centos.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for Debian (and most Linux distribution):
Keep sendmail (from sendmail.org) if you have significant sendmail experience.
Otherwise use Postfix.

https://wiki.debian.org/MTA

Comment: Do you mean to use Sendmail to relay to external server?

Comment: I found this nice post that uses postfix: http://www.linuxmail.info/postfix-smtp-gateway/  . Thanks a lot.